# Regex to match words only in long string with special characters

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I have a javascript function where I am trying to match every word in a long string, I have the match working for basically just exploding on spaces, although I would like to modify my regex to automatically remove special characters, such as !, - etc.

For example:

```
var a = 'This! is a sample sentence, only words should be extracted from it!!';
```

I'm looking for the result of the regex to be

```
{This,is,a,sample,sentence,only,words,should,be,extracted,from,it}
```

Comment: `s.split(/\W+/)` or `s.match(/\w+/g)`

Comment: What is your definition of word?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
> var a = 'This! is a sample sentence, only words should be extracted from it!!';

> a.match(/\w+/g);

["This", "is", "a", "sample", "sentence", "only", "words", "should", "be", "extracted", "from", "it"]
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of splitting, consider "matching" on `**word** characters:

```
var a = 'This! is a sample sentence, only words should be extracted from it!!';
a.match(/\w+/g);
//["This", "is", "a", "sample", "sentence", "only", "words", "should", "be", "extracted", "from", "it"]
```

Grabbing only word characters means anything not in the character class `[A-Za-z0-9_]` is stripped out and treated as a delimiter.